# robot framework string row comparison

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robot framework.

I have two strings:

**${str1}:**

```
  C        100.1.12.0/29 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
  L        100.1.12.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
  C        100.1.13.0/29 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
  L        100.1.13.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
  C        172.16.166.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
  L        172.16.166.151/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
  C        192.168.1.3 is directly connected, Loopback3
  C        192.168.11.2 is directly connected, Loopback1
  C        192.168.11.3 is directly connected, Loopback2
```

**${str2}:**

```
  C        200.1.12.0/29 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
  L        200.1.12.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
  C        200.1.13.0/29 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
  L        100.1.13.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
  C        172.16.166.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
  L        172.16.166.151/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
  C        192.168.1.3 is directly connected, Loopback3
  C        192.168.11.2 is directly connected, Loopback1
  C        192.168.11.3 is directly connected, Loopback2
```

I've to compare and see if any of the IP address of {str2} are in {str1}. how to do that? can you guys help me with example please? is there a way to treat each row as row in this string?

Comment: One more questions: how to split {str2} in columns so that I can find if any of the ip addresses are in {str1}. kind advise if there are any other options.

Comment: You can study string library. [Split To Lines](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20To%20Lines) and [Split String](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String). Eventually it could be done with a regex. Shall IP on line [n] in str1 and str2 always match? Or can the IP in str1 and str2 be unordered?

Comment: Thanks Akane. yes - IP is the key. it should match. can you help me with example please. I am new to robot framework.

Comment: Do you know how to write python code? This would likely be much simpler in a python-based keyword.